# Why does NIFI Flow in one machine can't sync the other machine occasionally?

Tags: apache-nifi

I get the ERROR log and solve it by using the same flow by copying the one to others. However, many suggestion tells me to delete the different flows,and then the flow would be generated automatically. Sometimes this way can work,but can't do it now. More important,the log does show the reason why flow would be different? How to avoid this error?TIA

NIFI-APP LOG:
[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

[image]

Comment: nifi and zookeeper version?

Comment: the error means that somehow the flow in your local nifi is no longer the same as the cluster, but its unclear how you go in this state, are there steps you can take to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @TahaNaqvi Thanks.NIFI-1.10.0 and ZK-3.5.6.Any help is appreciate!

Comment: @BryanBende Not Sure the scenario,Nifi just running continually before it shut down.But some log are helpful,and i've updated the issue as above pic

Comment: Still can't really tell the cause. The only way this should happen is if one of the nodes disconnected from the cluster and then you went to the NiFi UI of that disconnected node and changed something in the flow and then tried to join it back to the cluster.

Comment: @BryanBende Thanks you very much.i dont have idea to find the cause.Before that,I snap ERROR Log in Nifi-app.log.How to analyse the cause for Node disconnected?